# Dynamically created private variables?

Tags: php

I have a set of classes which hold state for the database. It's like a micro-ORM pattern. So for this solution I load in the structure of a few tables as dynamic properties to the class so that the class looks something like:

- Object

  - [tbl_name]

    - attribute1
    - attribute2
    - attribute3
  - [tbl_name]

    - attribute1
    - attribute2
    - attribute3

All of the attributes are public properties because I set them with something like this:

```
$object->{$table_name}->{$attribute} = 'foobar';
```

What I'd like though is for these dynamically set properties to be private. Why? Well because, and please don't miss the irony here, I want to make them public again through an overloaded getter/setter using __get() and __set(). Again we come back to the question of why. Well actually for "getting" I would have been fine with a public property but for setting I want to apply some logic before allowing the setting. Here's my simplified __set() function which gives you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public function __set ( $property , $value ) {

    if ( !in_array ($property , $blocked_properties) ) {
        $this->property = $value;
        $this->trigger_event ( $property );
    }
}
```

Make sense? I'm happy to solve this problem other ways but this seems like a very graceful way to do this if only I could dynamically set private instance variables.

Comment: Why not using a "real" ORM like doctrine 2? http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: Learning curve. Overkill. Flexibility. Not sure of the last one though but I have some ideas on what i want to do wrt to assigning my Enum objects to attributes, etc. that might not be supported in a ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make those actual properties, store them in a `private` array and access them only through magic methods:

```
class ORM {

    private $fields = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->fields[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->fields[$name] = $value;
    }

}
```

It behaves exactly how you want it.

Comment: Good suggestion. I've done this but now I'm running into a problem which is ... I think ... that when I assign an object to one of the properties I get a "Undefined property: stdClass::$ext_tables". My guess is that any attempt to GET something that is anywhere beyond the top level in the object graph will fail. Does this sound right or am I just not seeing something?